# MySQL - Hibernate SQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I created a query like this in my project with hibernate connected to a mysql database:

```
String sqlQuery = "select e.EXPEDITE_NUM_DISPLAY from receiver e where e.ID = 113";

List<Object> rows = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery).list();
```

The result list (rows) is a list with only one element with value = null (Ex. rows: [null]).

When i run the same query in MySQL workbench the value of the column is presented.

Any idea why in hibernate the returned value is null and not the right value?

Comment: Did you understand what ORM is?

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.journaldev.com/3422/hibernate-native-sql-query-example. Check if you have started the transaction

Comment: yes, I started the transaction. With other queries it works fine but only with this query i cannot extract the result.